# Defining variables from an association list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list of rules, something like

```
{f[x,y,z]-> F, g[x,y,z]-> G, D[f[x,y,z],x]-> fx,...}
```

I would like to assign the values to the variables like I would manually do:

```
F = f[x,y,z]; G = g[x,y,z]; fx = D[f[x,y,z],x];
```

Is there a way of achieving this without manually doing as above?

Comment: do you mean to have square brackets instead of ()?

Comment: Yes, edited. Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have an `Association`, or is it just a list of `Rule`s as in your post?

Comment: It is a list of rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following method, beware running the code with `Set` twice, because it will set values for `f` and `g`; or, if they are already defined, there will likely be a `TagSet` error.

---

If it's just a list of rules as in your OP, i.e.

```
Clear[f, g, F, G, fx]
rulesList = {f[x, y, z] -> F, g[x, y, z] -> G, D[f[x, y, z], x] -> fx};
```

you can do

```
Set @@@ (Reverse /@ rulesList);
```

Then, for instance, `G` evaluates to `g[x, y, z]`, as it should.